# hostname result as variable and then comparing it

Tags: batch-file

So. This is making me go crazy. My batch file knowledge is very basic.

So far I have this from other sources to set a variable to be the result from hostname

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET PCNAME=%%i
```

I'm still confused by this whole line but it works so I've kept it. I would like to understand what each part of it is doing though.

With that variable PCNAME I now want to do the following

> IF PCNAME = RDS then GOTO exit
>   else
>   GOTO main

But I can't get this IF ELSE part to work (the above I know isn't true code but it's just to explain what I'd like to do).

So to sum up.

Create a variable from the result of hostname.
Compare that variable to see if it matches RDS. If it does, then quit, if it doesn't go onto another part of the batch file.

I was thinking of looking to see if its easier to do in Powershell instead. My knowledge of that is mega basic as well but looks like Powershell is easier to use than batch files.

Comment: If you read the help file for the IF command you will clearly see what the syntax is for using ELSE

Comment: [if /?](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html), [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: This line is simple. it assigns a token (%%i) to the output of the command hostname and sets another variable with that same name.. pretty useless as you could simply do `set PCNAME=%computername%` or eve better, just use the `%computername%` preset variable.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks Squashman for the warm welcome. I've always had issues making sense of the CMD help file examples, much as the same of DOS help way back when, hence I thought I'd ask here as everyone seems helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. In the morning, and as Gerhard Barnard mentioned I realised I could just use `%computername%` which works

```
@echo off
IF %computername% EQU MyPC (
    echo MyPC 
) else (
    echo Do nothing
)
```

Comment: As a **best** practice I would advise that you use this syntax when doing string comparisons. `IF "%computername%"=="MyPC"`. Also remember that the string comparisons are case sensitive.  Use the `/I` option for a case insensitive match.

Comment: @Squashman OK thanks. I'm having trouble understanding the help file for IF and ss64.com hasn't made it any easier. So I'm curious to know what the, easy to understand difference is between EQU and == It's difficult understanding where an issue lies in the BATCH file as well due to no ability to step through the code.

Comment: `EQU, NEQ, GTR,GEQ,LSS, and LEQ` are normally used for comparing integers. While they can be used to compare strings, it is better to use `==` for that. What do you mean you cannot step through code?

Comment: @Squashman Thanks, that makes more sense.  Regarding the step through comment, I've searched for the option to step through code in a batch file line by line to debug it. But everyone says this isn't possible with BATCH files. The only way I've semi done it, which isn't great, is stick PAUSEs in various locations I believe I may have errors.